# How can we add scrolling text in cocos2d by using UITextView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextview, cocos2d-iphone

I want a UITextView in cocos2d. I used  in init method I wrote the code ,

```
 UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, windowSize.height/2,windowSize.width/2)];
 textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 textView.text = @"I am First enemy";
 [textView setEditable:NO]; 

 [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]addSubview:textView];
```

the orientation is in this way

```
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:CCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

I need the text to appear in landscape mode, but I am getting the text in following way.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b0de877fb2.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b0de877fb2.png)

How can I make the text to appear in the landScape mode. I am working in cocos2d. CanOI scroll the text ? What should i add to make the text scroll up and down.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the below url I found my answer

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3210

I used

```
textView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS( 90.0f ));
```